# Print all search results from a custom site

Tags: python, web, python-requests

How can I make, that if I give the command, my program prints all search results from a custom site (in my example: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=test)

I want something like this:

```
site = f'https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q={search}'
for line in site.content:
    if str(line).startswith("<a"):
        print(str(line))
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: What specifically is wrong with your current attempt(s)? This question is very vague and broad

Comment: I'm searching for a way, to get the html code of the website, if I have this, I can make the other things

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the selenium webscraping package.

First run: `pip install selenium`

then use the following script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=test")
time.sleep(2)

text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body").text  


print(text)
```

Note that if you press crtl+shift+i you will get to the environment where you can find the _element_by_css_selector that the scraper needs to print. You can use this for all kinds of websites. For further reference you need to check out the Selenium documentation ;)

Comment: Doesn't this need a GUI? I have a cli linux server ..

Answer (score 0):

This site loads the search results dynamically through Javascript. Loading the page through requests and parsing it with BeautifulSoup won't work. The solution is to load the page with [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/). This example will work out of the box on colab:

```
!apt update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!pip install selenium

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
web = 'https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=test'
path = '/usr/bin/chromedriver' #set the path of your chromedriver file

options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(web)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

results = [i.get_text() for i in soup.find_all('li')]
```

Results:

```
['API Reference...– The extension name to load. It must be dot separated like\nregular Python imports if accessing a sub-module. e.g.\nfoo.test if you want to import foo/test.py.\n\nRaises\n\nExtensionNotFound – The extension could not be imported.\nExtensionAlrea...', "Commands...two are equivalent:\nfrom discord.ext import commands\n\nbot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')\n\n@bot.command()\nasync def test(ctx):\n    pass\n\n# or:\n\n@commands.command()\nasync def test(ctx):\n    pass\n\nbot.add_command(test)\n\n\nSince the Bot.com...", 'Migrating to v0.10.0....channels\nServer.members\n\nSome examples of previously valid behaviour that is now invalid\nif client.servers[0].name == "test":\n    # do something\n\n\nSince they are no longer lists, they no longer support indexing or any operation other than...', "Migrating to v1.0...ow use a File pseudo-namedtuple to upload a single file.\n# before\nawait client.send_file(channel, 'cool.png', filename='testing.png', content='Hello')\n\n# after\nawait channel.send('Hello', file=discord.File('cool.png', 'testing.png'))\n\n\nThis..."]
```

Comment: Doesn't this need a GUI? I have a cli linux server ...

Comment: No, this example runs selenium in headless mode. Try it out.