# How to scrape a webpage that uses JavaScript to build the HTML?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a scraper made in python2 using requests and beautifulsoup. We do not want to use selenium. Now the website we are **scraping** has changed its some page. The page is now building the elements on the page using javascript. I want to scrape the page in which the source code is getting generated with javascript - how can this be done?

Comment: Indeed, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66107893/11380795) example how to use Beautifulsoup with Selenium.

Comment: Please use Python3. https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: @baduker sorry i forgot to mentioned that we are not allow to use selenium.

Comment: @GulshanKumar, well, that's too bad. :,(